# Crawl more than one URL and find same words number of occurences in URL's

Tags: python, html, url, web-crawler

I have a crawler that parse wikipedia page (Rwanda Genocide). As you can see it works perfect for one URL, and it finds occurences number of 'genocide ' word. But what I am trying to do is parsing more than one url (let's say I wanna crawl total 8 genocide links.) All wikipedia links have the same HTML pattern so paragraph and body_text variables will work for all URL's. How can I read and save other URL in the same python file ?

```
import requests
import urllib.request
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from urllib.request import urlopen
from collections import Counter
import re
def my_url_function(url):


    URL = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rwandan_genocide'
    response = requests.get(urls)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    paragraph = soup.find('div',{'id':'mw-content-text'}, {'class':'mw-content-ltr'}).tbody

    #print(paragraph)


    body_text = soup.findAll("div", class_="mw-parser-output")[0].findAll('p')
    body_text_big = ""
    for i in body_text:
        body_text_big = body_text_big +i.text

    print(body_text_big)

    text_file = open("Output.txt", "w")

    text_file.write(body_text_big)

    text_file.close()


    occurrences = body_text_big.count("genocide")
    print('Number of occurrences of the word :', occurrences)

# read URLs into list `urls`
with open("urls.txt", "r") as urlsFile:

    urls = urlsFile.read().splitlines() 

print(urls)
```

Comment: First, make sure you're using the same variable name everywhere -- you've got `url`, `URL`, and `urls` in there. For multiple URLs in a list, iterate over the list with a `for` loop, passing each URL to your function. Make sure you're writing to your results text file in append mode so you don't delete your data each time through.

Comment: Please don't artificially "tag" your title, e.g. with `(Python)`. Stack Overflow has real tags, and they are sufficient.

Comment: Hello @MattDMo, how can I create separate append function for every url?

Comment: You can name the output text file after the URL. `filename = url.split("/")[-1] + ".txt"`.